# Change /lang order with basePath and enabled international routing in Next

Tags: next.js, internationalization, url-routing

Given a Next.js app with enabled i18n routing and `basePath: '/blahblah'`.

The problem I facing is that translated route now is `/blahblah/en`. Due to certain requirements I need it to be `/en/blahblah`. How can I achieve it? Rewrites doesn't work.